Approximating the root $x\in(0,1/2)$ of $\frac{(1-n)^{n-1}}{n^n}x^n+x-1=0$, where $0<n<1$
I have the following equation:
$$\frac{(1-n)^{n-1}}{n^n}x^n+x-1=0$$
where $0<n<1$.
I know a solution for $x$ always exists in the range $(0, \frac{1}{2})$, but I'm unsure if it can be solved for exactly. I was hoping there was a method to obtain an approximate analytical solution, or perhaps tighter analytical bounds on the solution, in terms of $n$.

This is not a polynomial equation. For that, $n$ should be a positive integer.

Thanks, I've updated the question.

This is trinomial equation for which there are series solutions

With the substitution
$$
u= \frac{{(1 - n)^{n - 1} }}{{n^n }}x^n ,
$$
the equation becomes
$$
u + \frac{n}{(1 - n)^{1 - 1/n}}u^{1/n}  - 1 = 0.
$$
Employing the formula in this answer with $\alpha=\beta=1/n$ and $\omega=-n/(1 - n)^{1 - 1/n}$, we obtain
$$
u^{1/n}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}\left( {\frac{n}{{(1 - n)^{1 - 1/n} }}} \right)^k \frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{n}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{n} - k + 1} \big)}}}.
$$
Returning to the original variable, we find
$$
x = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k!}}\left( {\frac{n}{{(1 - n)^{1 - 1/n} }}} \right)^{k + 1} \frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{n}} \big)}}{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{n} - k + 1} \big)}}}.
$$
The only thing that needs to be checked is the convergence of the series, as it is evaluated at the boundary of convergence. I anticipate that it will converge based on the alternating series test.
Addendum. Up to a constant factor that depends only on $n$, the $k^{\text{th}}$ term of the series is
$$
\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{k^{3/2} }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{k^{5/2} }}} \right),
$$
which proves the convergence. This asymptotics can be deduced from Stirling's formula.

There is no closed-form expression for the solution unless $n$ is a simple fraction with denominator $2$, $3$, or $4$. Newton–Raphson gives rapidly converging results for this type of equation. You could simplify it a little by the scaling $$t:=\frac{1-n}nx\quad\text{with}\quad f(t):=\frac{t^n}{1-n}+\frac n{1-n}t-1.$$
Then, starting with some chosen  $t_0$, we iterate with the function
$$g(t):=t-\frac{f(t)}{f'(t)}=\frac{1-n}n\frac{1-t^n}{1+t^{n-1}}$$
to get $t_1,t_2,$ etc. For example, with $n=\frac12$, from $t_0=\frac14$, we get $t_1=\frac16$, and already $t_2=0.1715476...$, which compares with the exact solution $3-2\surd2=0.1715725...$ .

If we use $t_0=\left(\frac{1-n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{   n}}$, by Darboux theorem, the solution will be reached without any overshoot.

@Claude : I tried your suggestion, also for $n=\frac12$. That gives $t_0=\frac19$, which coincidentally yields $t_1=\frac16$ too. Perhaps your formula for $t_0$ results in faster convergence for values of $n$ away from $\frac12$; but anyway I don't know how you obtained it.

Starting from @John Bentin's answer
$$f(t)=t^n+nt+(n-1)\qquad \text{with}\qquad 0 \leq t \leq W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)$$ the function is upper bounded by
$$g(t)=t^n+nt^n+(n-1)\quad \implies \quad t_0=\left(\frac{1-n}{1+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{
   n}}$$
Since $f(t_0)<0$ and $f''(t_0)<0$, by Darboux theorem, Newton method will converge without any overshoot.
A little bit of analysis shows that a better initial estimate could be
$$t_0==\left(\frac{1-n}{1+n}\right)^{\frac{2+n}{3n}}$$
The table reproduces the value of the estimate, the value of the first iterate of Newton method and the solution for a few values of $n$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & t_0 & t_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 0.254665 & 0.269110 &  0.269417 \\
 0.10 & 0.245442 & 0.259770 &  0.260065 \\
 0.15 & 0.235927 & 0.250108 &  0.250389 \\
 0.20 & 0.226116 & 0.240103 &  0.240368 \\
 0.25 & 0.216000 & 0.229732 &  0.229981 \\
 0.30 & 0.205566 & 0.218972 &  0.219202 \\
 0.35 & 0.194797 & 0.207796 &  0.208004 \\
 0.40 & 0.183673 & 0.196171 &  0.196357 \\
 0.45 & 0.172168 & 0.184064 &  0.184226 \\
 0.50 & 0.160250 & 0.171435 &  0.171573 \\
 0.55 & 0.147879 & 0.158239 &  0.158353 \\
 0.60 & 0.135007 & 0.144426 &  0.144515 \\
 0.65 & 0.121575 & 0.129933 &  0.130000 \\
 0.70 & 0.107507 & 0.114692 &  0.114739 \\
 0.75 & 0.092705 & 0.098614 &  0.098644 \\
 0.80 & 0.077040 & 0.081595 &  0.081612 \\
 0.85 & 0.060333 & 0.063495 &  0.063503 \\
 0.90 & 0.042318 & 0.044124 &  0.044126 \\
 0.95 & 0.022548 & 0.023179 &  0.023179 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Edit
Even if it does not mean to much
$$-1\leq f(t) \leq 2 W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=0.557$$
$$-0.01958\leq f(t_0) \leq 0$$
$$-0.00028\leq f(t_1) \leq 0$$
